Is Shaken Baby Syndrome Discredited?
An opinion piece by Jeff Kukucka & David Faigman in scientific American
makes the claim

In a last-minute effort to save the life of a man on death row, a bipartisan group of Texas legislators has just done something extraordinary: they have unanimously subpoenaed Robert Roberson, convicted in 2003 of killing his daughter based on the now-discredited theory of shaken baby syndrome, to testify before them five days after he was scheduled to be executed, effectively forcing the state to keep him alive.

Emphasis added for clarity. 
For reference NIH description of shaken baby syndrome.
The piece later claims that

In fact, a 2024 study found that the injuries historically used to diagnose shaking are actually more likely to result from accidents than from shaking.

citin Spanish study by Cris Brook "Witnessing abusive head trauma: Accidents show higher rates of intracranial pathologies than shaking".
Is Shaken Baby Syndrome Discredited?

This is an awkward question because it's answering itself. The only thing left is a (rather pedantic) argument about the meaning of the word "discredited".

@CJR I can't believe that scientific American would hide behind weasel words. Discredited == Not corresponding with reality in layman's terms

Is it discredited if "Shaken baby syndrome is real with these symptoms, but the symptoms alone are not diagnostic of shaken baby syndrome" is a true statement? Doctors would say no, of course not, but this was written by two law people and I don't know if it's valid to call it discredited legally.

The question doesn't correctly present what was actually stated. The article doesn't say that "Shaken Baby Syndrome" is discredited. It says that the "Theory of Shaken Baby Syndrome" is discredited. That theory may very well be the no-longer held belief that a certain set of symptoms are legal proof that the baby's injuries are a result of being shaken.

Maybe use another quote instead of Scientific American. For example, NJM: "[I]t’s controversial in the biomechanics community, particularly when a baby shows no physical evidence of being assaulted…. Biomechanics scientists disagree on whether shaking alone can create forces strong enough to cause the intracranial trauma needed to diagnose the syndrome, which is also known as abusive head trauma" (The question is, what evidence is strongest?)

@RayButterworth I was unable to find source distinguishing between theory of sbs and plain sbs. It seems that the article is using these interchangeably. Do you have better search-fu results?

National Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Children indicates that the term ‘shaken baby syndrome’ is outdated and doesn’t cover the other causes of "non-accidental head injury" in infants and young children.

I don't think "The Theory of XXX Syndrome" is anything more than a rhetorical expression, and theory is interchangeable with mechanism or etiology

Certainly some people have shaken their babies who later died. The problems here are (1) is this capital murder or some lesser crime, and more importantly, (2) whether other issues can yield the same kinds of evidence and result in a completely wrongful conviction. The concept of shaken baby syndrome has not been discredited. It is the triad of evidence formerly used to prove shaken baby syndrome in court that has widely been discredited.

@DavidHammen "shaken baby syndrome in court that has widely been discredited." This is at the heart of the question. Where might one find references for this?

@pinegulf It's right there in the Scientific American article you yourself referenced. The answer to your question "has shaken baby syndrome been discredited" is no, it has not. That would be tantamount to saying that shaken baby syndrome doesn't exist. However, the evidence that once was treated as incontrovertible signs of shaken baby syndrome has been discredited as being incontrovertible.


Is Shaken Baby Syndrome Discredited?

No, it is not. There have been eyewitnessed (and in some cases, videotaped) cases of a baby being violently shaken where the baby later died with all of the symptoms of shaken baby syndrome. This is well documented in the scientific journal article referenced by the Scientific American article.
What has been discredited is the triad of evidence (subdural hematoma, retinal hemorrhages, and hypoxic-ischemic encephalopathy) accompanied with an absence of signs of accidental head injury that was once treated as legally incontrovertible signs of shaken baby syndrome. The same article, and many others, (those are just two of many) argue that accidental injury accounts for a good portion of the infant deaths that pass that triad of tests. The supposed legally incontrovertible evidence is no longer viewed as incontrovertible.
